# split Arabic text into sentences in php ( Split RTL Languages )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arabic, right-to-left

i need to split the large Arabic sentence in to chunks , its not work properly, when i process this text with `ajax` it changes from `RTL` to `LTR` is there some way to process it in `rtl` . in browser it works fine but on server side it changes to left-to-right order . i want to process this in `right-to-left` order on server side (`PHP`) .

**sample text**

```
=='''التوفي'''==
    يعد التوفي من السكاكر المفضّلة لدى عدد كبير من الناس وباختلاف الأعمار ، وهو عبارة عن خليط سكاكري  يحضر بعدة طرق سهلة
 ومكوناته متوافرة في المنزل، ويستخدم مع العديد من الحلويات لتزينها وإعطائها النكهة المميزة، وفي هذا المقال سوف نعرض بعض الحلويات التي تتكون من التوفي اللذيذ.
```

**code**

```
var innerText = "=='''التوفي'''==
يعد التوفي من السكاكر المفضّلة لدى عدد كبير من الناس وباختلاف الأعمار ، وهو عبارة عن خليط سكاكري  يحضر بعدة طرق سهلة ومكوناته متوافرة في المنزل، ويستخدم مع العديد من الحلويات لتزينها وإعطائها النكهة المميزة، وفي هذا المقال سوف نعرض بعض الحلويات التي تتكون من التوفي اللذيذ." 
var parts = innerText.split(" ");
var values = [];
var i = 0;
var tmpVar = "";
$.each(parts, function(index, value) {
    if(tmpVar.length < 55)
    {
        tmpVar += " " + value;
    }else{
        values[i] = tmpVar.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        i++;
        tmpVar = value;
    }
});
if(values.length < 1 &&  parts.length > 0){
    values[0] = tmpVar;
}
```

**output**

```
 [" =='''التوفي'''== يعد التوفي من السكاكر المفضّلة لدى عدد", "كبير من الناس وباختلاف الأعمار ، وهو عبارة عن خليط سكاكري", "يحضر بعدة طرق سهلة ومكوناته متوافرة في المنزل، ويستخدم مع", "العديد من الحلويات لتزينها وإعطائها النكهة المميزة، وفي"]
```

Outputs changes to `LTR`.
[image: java-script output]

**Browser output:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by output changes to LTR ?!, please explain

Comment: @HossamMagdy when i split it in chunks it show fine in browser but in java-script array it changes from Right-to-left to left-to-right order .

Comment: Javascript array has no "direction". It just stores values in elements. !